# Request Body Validation on Class Level in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, bean-validation

I have a dto class and I am applying a class level custom constraint to it. My problem is I want it to behave differently in case of create and update apis. In case of property validation it is easy to achieve with different annotations but on class level I am having some issues about finding a proper solution. Here is a minimalistic example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
interface Create
interface Update

@ValidApiDto(groups = [Create::class, Update::class])
data class ApiDto(
    val id: Long,
    val metaData: MetaDataDto,
    // many other properties
)

@Constraint(validatedBy = [ApiDtoValidator::class])
@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.CLASS])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class ValidApiDto(
    val message: String = "Invalid api dto!",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)


class ApiDtoValidator: ConstraintValidator<ValidApiDto, ApiDto> {
    override fun isValid(dto: ApiDto, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
        // My logic comes here. Adapt behavior based on update or create
        return true
    }
}

@RestController
@Validated
class MyRestController {
    
    @PostMapping("/post")
    @Validated(value = [Create::class])
    fun post(@Valid dto: ApiDto): ResponseEntity<*>? {
        return null
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/put")
    @Validated(value = [Update::class])
    fun update(@Valid dto: ApiDto): ResponseEntity<*>? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have different logics in one validator?

I tried to find the passed group by the context but it gives me all possible groups, which are create and update in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Validation groups](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/3.0/jakarta-bean-validation-spec-3.0.html#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence) is the way to filter constraints, i.e. you are grouping constraints into groups and, depending on a condition, execute the constraints from a group.

If you'd want to have a conditional validator implementation what you can do instead is:

1. Add an attribute to your constraint annotation:

```kotlin
@Repeatable
@Constraint(validatedBy = [ApiDtoValidator::class])
@Target(allowedTargets = [AnnotationTarget.CLASS])
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class ValidApiDto(
    val message: String = "Invalid api dto!",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = [],
    // add some enum, or a boolean, whatever you find more suitable:
    val type: ConstraintType = ConstraintType.CREATE 
)
```

2. Annotate your DTO using the new attribute and groups as:

```kotlin
@ValidApiDto(type = ConstraintType.CREATE, groups = [Create::class])
@ValidApiDto(type = ConstraintType.UPDATE, groups = [Update::class])
data class ApiDto(
    val id: Long,
    val metaData: MetaDataDto,
    // many other properties
)
```

This way you are assigning constraints with a different configuration to a different validation group and only a corresponding constraint will be applied in that group.

In your implementation of constraint validator you'll have access to the annotation attribute:

```kotlin
class ApiDtoValidator: ConstraintValidator<ValidApiDto, ApiDto> {
    override fun initialize(ValidApiDto constraintAnnotation) {
        // access your configured type value:
        val type constraintAnnotation.type();
    }
    override fun isValid(dto: ApiDto, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
        // My logic comes here. Adapt behavior based on update or create
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey , Thank you very much for your response. That is actually what I was trying to avoid. I wanted to achieve this solely based on the group that I give to @Validated anno but it seems that there is no other way to achieve it. I will accept your answer. Thanks for your time! Edit: It seems that I need at least 15 reputation to upvote your answer?

Comment: One quick feedback is that we also need to annotate our ValidApiDto annotation with the @Repeatable annotation so that we can annotate our ApiDto two times with the same annotation :)) Could you please edit your answer @mark_o?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the post. Btw another alternative is to have two different constant annotations, you could create an abstract validator implementation to share the common logic and then add specifics in the implementations, but still you'll have two constraints added, each living in its own validation group.